# Why can't Vala connect signals to delegates?

Tags: delegates, closures, vala

I used to think that a delegate behaves like a method reference in Vala. However, I don't understand why the following code doesn't work:

```
class Bar {
    public signal void bar_signal();
}

class Foo : Object {
    public Foo( int i, Bar bar ) {
        bar.bar_signal.connect( bar_handler( i + 1 ) );
    }

    public delegate void Handler();

    private static Handler bar_handler( int j ) {
        return () =>
        {
            stdout.printf( "handler: %d\n", j );
        };
    }
}

public static void main( string[] args ) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    new Foo( 1, bar ); // will be finalized immediately
    bar.bar_signal();
}
```

The idiom of this code is actually quite typical in JavaScript, which makes heavy use of closures. Sadly, `valac` says:

> Test.vala:8.33-8.45: error: Argument 1: Cannot convert from `Foo.Handler` to `Bar.bar_signal`

At first, I thought that this might be due to the following [incompatibility of delegate types](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Manual/Delegates):

> Instance and static delegate instances are not interchangeable.

However, the error doesn't change if I put a `static` into the declaration of the delegate.

I searched the web but only came across [an old mailing list entry](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2009-December/msg00073.html) from 2009, which says that this is a bug in Vala. Is that right? And if so: How can it be that this bug still isn't fixed, 7 years later?

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed a known bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=604781

A workaround is to invoke it using a closure:

```
bar.bar_signal.connect( () => { bar_handler( i + 1 ); } );
```